# What does null mean here?

Tags: sql, null

What does null mean in this script? Does it mean that the column can have null values or does it mean that the column's default value is nul?

```
    CREATE TABLE product ( product_nbr int NOT NULL,
    product_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    product_status_code char(10) NOT NULL,
    start_date date NULL,
    end_date date NULL,
    raw_material_cost decimal(12,2) NULL,
    primary key (product_nbr)
    )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the column accepts null values. This is the direct opposite of the `NOT NULL` declaration you see for your other columns, and is in fact the default declaration.

For a column to have a default value of `NULL`, the declaration is `DEFAULT NULL`. That in turn implies, of course, that the column accepts null values.

Comment: CREATE TABLE product ( product_nbr int NOT NULL, product_name varchar(40) NOT NULL, product_status_code char(10) NOT NULL, start_date date, end_date date, raw_material_cost decimal(12,2), primary key (product_nbr) )..so is this the query the same as the one in the question..

Comment: @rgksugan: they are not quite the same. Your SQL in comments is valid SQL-92 syntax, whereas your SQL in the question is not. Using the 'NULL' keyword in SQL DDL to flag a column as nullable is a vendor extension to the Standard and I'm guessing the vendor in question is Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

It basically means both since the a column allows NULL and there is no default value set for the column.  If you insert into the table and don't specify a value and there is no default value for the column, the value will be null (undefined).  If the column is set to NOT NULL and there is no default value, you will receive an error because the column is not allowed to be NULL.